# New Content type formatting

Tags: nodes

I have a person who wants to have feature jobs on his site.

I've already got the descrption allow full html and got WYSIWYG going so he can add pictures and descriptions beside the pictures etc. but he wants it even simpler.  He wants to have images and then a description that goes beside each image, then be able to add more images with descriptions as necessary.  He wants them to look as follows:

*image1 *description1

*image2 *description2

With description one being a bunch of text most likely bullet points.

He's wanting the image/descriptions to be tied to one another.  I'm pretty new so not sure how to do that.  I am comfortable being able to use CSS to format the content if I can create a type that ties the image/description together like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind installing a new module you should check the [double field](https://drupal.org/project/double_field) module.

> Double field is a small module written to provide extensions to Drupal's core Fields. By this module you can divide your fields into two seporate parts.

By using this module you can actually tie two fields together, and by clicking on add more you will have an image and its description tied together